# json decoding cyrillic from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get cyrillic data from MySQL database using php
I set utf-8

```
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("SET character_set_client = utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = utf8");
```

And when i set cyrillic data in db it works properly, but when I'm trying to get it:

```
 $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["first_name"] = $row["first_name"];
    $product["last_name"] = $row["last_name"];
    $product["vk_id"] = $row["vk_id"];
    $product["points"] = $row["points"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["users"], $product);
 echo json_encode($response);
```

And it gives me `\u0416\u0430\u043c\u0431\u044b\u043b`

and when I change `json_encode($response);`
to `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

it gives me :`Р–Р°РјР±С‹Р`

How can I get readable cyrillic data?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, stop using `mysql` extension instead use `mysqli` or `pdo`. `MySQL` is vulnerable to sql injections. For more info read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
Secondly, if use `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` or `mysql_set_charset('uft8')` to set seesion encoding to utf8in your vulnerable case.
Thirdly, check encoding and colation in your database field, most likely it has something like latin1, change it to utf8_general_ci.
And lastly, i suspect that you are viewing results in browser? If this is the case then set headers in php likes this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: It should be `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` when serving JSON. `</pedant>`